# Error connecting to mongodb server using mongodb.driver 2.10.3

Tags: c#, mongodb

I've tried using the mongodb connection method for my cluster but I get a timeout error. The cluster has 3 shards (00, 01, 02) and they all healthy according to my mongo dashboard. I can also see read operations being registered on the primary shard. No matter what query I run I get the same timeout exception.

```cs
var client = new MongoClient("mongodb+srv://bugbeeb:*******@csharptest-yzm6y.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority");
var database = client.GetDatabase("test");
database.ListCollectionNames().ToList();
```

> Unhandled exception. System.TimeoutException: A timeout occured after 30000ms selecting a server using CompositeServerSelector{ Selectors = MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient+AreSessionsSupportedServerSelector, LatencyLimitingServerSelector{ AllowedLatencyRange = 00:00:00.0150000 } }. Client view of cluster state is { ClusterId : "1", ConnectionMode : "ReplicaSet", Type : "ReplicaSet", State : "Disconnected", Servers : [{ ServerId: "{ ClusterId : 1, EndPoint : "Unspecified/csharptest-shard-00-00-yzm6y.mongodb.net:27017" }", EndPoint: "Unspecified/csharptest-shard-00-00-yzm6y.mongodb.net:27017", State: "Disconnected", Type: "Unknown", HeartbeatException: "MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An exception occurred while opening a connection to the server.
>    ---> MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An exception occurred while receiving a message from the server.
>    ---> System.IO.EndOfStreamException: Attempted to read past the end of the stream.
>      at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Misc.StreamExtensionMethods.ReadBytesAsync(Stream stream, Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, TimeSpan timeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.ReceiveBufferAsync()
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.ReceiveBufferAsync()
>      at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.ReceiveBufferAsync(Int32 responseTo, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.ReceiveMessageAsync(Int32 responseTo, IMessageEncoderSelector encoderSelector, MessageEncoderSettings messageEncoderSettings, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      at MongoDB.Driver.Core.WireProtocol.CommandUsingQueryMessageWireProtocol`1.ExecuteAsync(IConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.IsMasterHelper.GetResultAsync(IConnection connection, CommandWireProtocol`1 isMasterProtocol, CancellationToken 
>   cancellationToken)
>      at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.ConnectionInitializer.InitializeConnectionAsync(IConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.OpenHelperAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.OpenHelperAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Servers.ServerMonitor.HeartbeatAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)", LastUpdateTimestamp: "2020-05-05T01:54:47.5568045Z" }, { ServerId: "{ ClusterId : 1, EndPoint : "Unspecified/csharptest-shard-00-01-yzm6y.mongodb.net:27017" }", EndPoint: "Unspecified/csharptest-shard-00-01-yzm6y.mongodb.net:27017", State: "Disconnected", Type: "Unknown", HeartbeatException: "MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An exception 
>   occurred while opening a connection to the server.
>    ---> MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An exception occurred while receiving a message from the server.
>    ---> System.IO.EndOfStreamException: Attempted to read past the end of the stream.
>      at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Misc.StreamExtensionMethods.ReadBytesAsync(Stream stream, Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, TimeSpan timeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.ReceiveBufferAsync()
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.ReceiveBufferAsync()
>      at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.ReceiveBufferAsync(Int32 responseTo, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.ReceiveMessageAsync(Int32 responseTo, IMessageEncoderSelector encoderSelector, MessageEncoderSettings messageEncoderSettings, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      at MongoDB.Driver.Core.WireProtocol.CommandUsingQueryMessageWireProtocol`1.ExecuteAsync(IConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.IsMasterHelper.GetResultAsync(IConnection connection, CommandWireProtocol`1 isMasterProtocol, CancellationToken 
>   cancellationToken)
>      at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.ConnectionInitializer.InitializeConnectionAsync(IConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.OpenHelperAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.OpenHelperAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Servers.ServerMonitor.HeartbeatAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)", LastUpdateTimestamp: "2020-05-05T01:54:47.5411460Z" }, { ServerId: "{ ClusterId : 1, EndPoint : "Unspecified/csharptest-shard-00-02-yzm6y.mongodb.net:27017" }", EndPoint: "Unspecified/csharptest-shard-00-02-yzm6y.mongodb.net:27017", State: "Disconnected", Type: "Unknown", HeartbeatException: "MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An exception 
>   occurred while opening a connection to the server.
>    ---> MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An exception occurred while receiving a message from the server.
>    ---> System.IO.EndOfStreamException: Attempted to read past the end of the stream.
>      at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Misc.StreamExtensionMethods.ReadBytesAsync(Stream stream, Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, TimeSpan timeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.ReceiveBufferAsync()
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.ReceiveBufferAsync()
>      at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.ReceiveBufferAsync(Int32 responseTo, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.ReceiveMessageAsync(Int32 responseTo, IMessageEncoderSelector encoderSelector, MessageEncoderSettings messageEncoderSettings, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      at MongoDB.Driver.Core.WireProtocol.CommandUsingQueryMessageWireProtocol`1.ExecuteAsync(IConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.IsMasterHelper.GetResultAsync(IConnection connection, CommandWireProtocol`1 isMasterProtocol, CancellationToken 
>   cancellationToken)
>      at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.ConnectionInitializer.InitializeConnectionAsync(IConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.OpenHelperAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.OpenHelperAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Servers.ServerMonitor.HeartbeatAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)", LastUpdateTimestamp: "2020-05-05T01:54:47.5159634Z" }] }.
>      at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Clusters.Cluster.ThrowTimeoutException(IServerSelector selector, ClusterDescription description)
>      at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Clusters.Cluster.WaitForDescriptionChangedHelper.HandleCompletedTask(Task completedTask)
>      at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Clusters.Cluster.WaitForDescriptionChanged(IServerSelector selector, ClusterDescription description, Task descriptionChangedTask, TimeSpan timeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Clusters.Cluster.SelectServer(IServerSelector selector, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      at MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient.AreSessionsSupportedAfterServerSelection(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      at MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient.AreSessionsSupported(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      at MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient.StartImplicitSession(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      at MongoDB.Driver.OperationExecutor.StartImplicitSession(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      at MongoDB.Driver.MongoDatabaseImpl.UsingImplicitSession[TResult](Func`2 func, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      at MongoDB.Driver.MongoDatabaseImpl.ListCollectionNames(ListCollectionNamesOptions options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      at MongoTest.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\bugbe\Documents\VSCode\Ch01\hello\Program.cs:line 17

Comment: Did you whitelist your IP?

Comment: That's what it was, I moved right after I set up my mongo atlas account, thank you!